# SMTP to Gmail Authenticated Relay not working email stuck in queue

Tags: email, gmail, smtp

I am following this document

http://kb.eclipseinc.com/kb/how-to-configure-iis-smtp-server-to-forward-emails-using-email-account/

and in places where it was talking about ports etc i used the information

### Gmail SMTP server settings

1. Gmail SMTP server name: smtp.gmail.com
2. Gmail SMTP username: your Gmail address
3. Gmail SMTP password: your password
4. Gmail SMTP port: 465

I also enabled TLS

but mails sent just get stuck in queue

**My Settings**

[image: SMTP_DeliverTab]
[image: Outbound Connections]
[image: Outbound Security]
[image: Advanced Delivery]
[image: Relay Restricions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mails sent just get stuck in queue

You need to use port 587 with TLS.

> - Gmail SMTP port (TLS): 587
> - Gmail SMTP port (SSL): 465

Source [What Are the Gmail SMTP Settings?](http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm)

---

#### I'm getting an error message that my app is not secure

> Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account myaccount@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards.

You need to change a setting on your Gmail account.

- Login to Gmail
- Go to "My account"
- Select "Sign-in & security"
- Scroll to the bottom of the page
- Set "Allow less secure apps" to "ON"

[image]

Try to send your emails again.

---

#### Allowing less secure apps to access your account

> Google may block sign-in attempts from some apps or devices that do
>   not use modern security standards. Since these apps and devices are
>   easier to break into, blocking them helps keep your account safe.
>
> Some examples of apps that do not support the latest security
>   standards include:
>
> - The Mail app on your iPhone or iPad with iOS 6 or below
> - The Mail app on your Windows phone preceding the 8.1 release
> - Some Desktop mail clients like Microsoft Outlook and Mozilla Thunderbird
>
> **Change account access for less secure apps**
>
> To help keep Google Apps users' accounts secure, we may block less
>   secure apps from accessing Google Apps accounts. As a Google Apps
>   user, you will see a "Password incorrect" error when trying to sign
>   in. If this is the case, you have two options:
>
> - Option 1: Upgrade to a more secure app that uses the most up to date security measures. All Google products, like Gmail, use the latest
>     security measures.
> - Option 2: Change your settings to allow less secure apps to access your account. We don't recommend this option because it might make it
>     easier for someone to break into your account. If you want to allow
>     access anyway, follow these steps:
>
>   1. Go to the "Less secure apps" section in My Account.
>   2. Next to "Access for less secure apps," select Turn on. (Note to Google Apps users: This setting is hidden if your administrator has
>        locked less secure app account access.)

Source [Allowing less secure apps to access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en-GB)

Comment: You are correct i was using the wrong port after changing to 587 i got one partial success saying google prevented the sign in attempt coz app doens't meet modern standards but then after that nothing

Comment: @SeanClt What is the exact error message?

Comment: no error message email just sits on the queue

Comment: @SeanClt So what is this "app doens't meet modern standards" then?

Comment: Message in the email : Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account myaccount@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards.

Comment: You need to change a setting on your Google account. I will update the answer.

Comment: thank you i just added screenshot of my settings, Next i m going to try my zoho account instead of gmail but i might not be able to test further before  monday Really appreciate the help

Comment: Answer updated. If you change as described Gmail should work.

Comment: Thank you I'll test this again and also post how I am sending the emails

Answer (score 1):

I may little late, experienced a similar issue, this was after May 30, 2022.

This feature is no longer supported as of May 30th, 2022. See [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?rd=1#zippy=%2Cuse-an-app-password).

> Use an App Password
>
> An App password is a 16-digit passcode that gives a non-Google app or device permission to access your Google Account. Learn more about how to [sign in using App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).